# WordPress Post Excerpt is not showing in my Recent Post Widget

Tags: php, widget, wordpress

I am using get_posts to retrieve posts information from database. It returns "Post title", "thumbnail", "post category", and "post excerpt". Everything is working fine but the problem is I am unable to show post excerpt.

Here is my code:

```
function widget ($args,$instance) {
   extract($args);

  $title = $instance['title'];
  $catid = $instance['catid'];
  $numberposts = $instance['numberposts'];
  $date = $instance['date'];
  $rss = $instance['rss'];

  // retrieve posts information from database
  global $wpdb;
  $posts = get_posts('post_type=post&numberposts='.$numberposts.'&category='.$catid);
  $out = '<ul>';

  if ($posts) {
      foreach($posts as $post) { 
      setup_postdata($post);
      $out .= '<li>'.get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'medium').'</li>';
      $out .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></li>';    
      $out .= '<li>'.$post->post_excerpt.'</li>';
      if ($date) $out .= '<li>'.date('d/m/Y', strtotime($post->post_date_gmt)).'</li>';
      }
  } 

  if ($rss) $out .= '<li><a href="'.get_category_link($catid).'feed/" class="rss">Category RSS</a></li>';
  $out .= '</ul>';

  //print the widget for the sidebar
  echo $before_widget;
  echo $before_title.$title.$after_title;
  echo $out;
  echo $after_widget;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$post->post_excerpt` does not get work the way you think it does. Most people think this is the same as the template tag `the_excerpt()`, and it is not

`the_excerpt()` is generated by truncating `get_the_content()`. `$post->post_excerpt` is not generated at all as this is user defined. This excerpt is the excerpt text manually added by the user in the post edit screen in the excerpt meta box. (This meta box is hidden by default, but can be enabled in the "Screen Options" tab on the top part of the screen). If the user did not specify a manual excerpt, `$post->post_excerpt` will return nothing, that is why you see this behavior

You have already set up your postdata, so you can just simply use the template tags directly, so in place of `$post->post_excerpt`, you can use `the_excerpt()`

**EDIT**

Thanks to the comment below, I did not take into account that the excerpt should not be echo'd straight away. In this case, you would make use of `get_the_excerpt()` which does not echo the text, but simply retrieves it.

Comment: If you need to build a formatted string before echoing (`the_excerpt()` will echo right then and there), you could capture that value using [`get_the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt), which would be a stand-in replacement for the `$post->post_excerpt` value.

Comment: You are correct. `get_the_excerpt()` will be the correct choice here. I actually haven't taken note that the excerpt should not be echo'd straight away. Thanks for that.